# Bluetooth Chat Sample - display received data to TextView

Tags: android, bluetooth

i am using the Bluetooth Chat sample to receive some Sensor-Data from my Arduino on my Android Device, so i deactivated the code for sending data and changed the code for receiving, that i get full String with my Sensor data (like that: Sensordata1,Sensordata2,Sensordata3,Sensordata4,Sensordata5,),split it into the particular Values and display it as an chat element to ListView.

Here is the changed code in the BluetoothChatFragment:

```
        byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                // construct a string from the valid bytes in the buffer
                String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);

                if(readMessage != null && readMessage.length() > 29) {

                    String seperateValues[] = readMessage.split(",");
                    String pressure_1 = seperateValues[0];
                    String pressure_2 = seperateValues[1];
                    String pressure_3 = seperateValues[2];
                    String pressure_4 = seperateValues[3];
                    String pressure_5 = seperateValues[4];

                    int pressure_1_int = Integer.parseInt(pressure_1);
                    int pressure_2_int = Integer.parseInt(pressure_2);
                    int pressure_3_int = Integer.parseInt(pressure_3);
                    int pressure_4_int = Integer.parseInt(pressure_4);
                    int pressure_5_int = Integer.parseInt(pressure_5);

                float pressure_1_float = (Float.parseFloat(pressure_1)) / 10;                         
                float pressure_2_float = (Float.parseFloat(pressure_2)) / 10;
                float pressure_3_float = (Float.parseFloat(pressure_3)) / 10;
                float pressure_4_float = (Float.parseFloat(pressure_4)) / 10;
                float pressure_5_float = (Float.parseFloat(pressure_5)) / 10;

                    pressure_1 = Float.toString(pressure_1_float);
                    pressure_2 = Float.toString(pressure_2_float);
                    pressure_3 = Float.toString(pressure_3_float);
                    pressure_4 = Float.toString(pressure_4_float);
                    pressure_5 = Float.toString(pressure_5_float);


          String completeString = pressure_1 + " " + 
          pressure_2 + " " + pressure_3 + " " + pressure_4 + " " + pressure_5;


                    mConversationArrayAdapter.add(completeString);
                    break;
```

This is not a really kind way to display data so i wanted to show the 5 values in single TextView fields...
I fit in TextView in the xml file (fragment_bluetooth_chat.xml) and called the TextView with:

```
TextView pressure1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
TextView pressure2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
TextView pressure3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
TextView pressure4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
TextView pressure5 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView5);
```

But Android studio does not accept the findViewById!?
What is my mistake?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Here is the xml (fragment_bluetooth_chat.xml):

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Druck1"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#575757" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Druck2"
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#575757" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Druck3"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#575757" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Druck4"
    android:id="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#575757" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/Druck5"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textColor="#575757" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: which method did you place the 'findViewById()' into?

Comment: onCreate() and i moved the declaration (TextView pressure1) to the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the TextViews to the other "Layout Views" in BluetoothChatFragment:

```
// Layout Views
private ListView mConversationView;
private EditText mOutEditText;
private Button mSendButton;
private TextView pressure1, pressure2, pressure3, pressure4, pressure5;
```

And bind the TextViews to the UI elements in the 'onViewCreated()' method:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mConversationView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.in);
    mOutEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit_text_out);
    mSendButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    pressure1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    pressure2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    pressure3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    pressure4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    pressure5 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView5);
}
```

Please note that in this case it's '**view**.findViewById()'.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You made my day!

Comment: Now Android Studio accepts findViewById() but the app is suddenly crashing after launch

Comment: @Fred - I think one should make this a new question (because it basically is a different problem) and include the code as well as the stack trace.